# Why can't auto, static keyword be used in formal parameter in function definitions?

Tags: c

Compiler - Mingw gcc
OS - Windows 10

Statement 1:

```
void fun(auto int a){} // statement 1 - Error!
```

Statement 2:

```
void fun(static int a){} // statement 2- Error!
```

Statement 3:

```
static void fun(auto int a){} //statement 3- Error!
```

Statement 4:

```
void fun(register int a){} // statement 4-No error(Valid)
```

Why do statements 1,2 and 3 generate compile time errors but statement 4 not?

What is the problem while using auto in formal parameters in function?

Here is the error output:

*error: storage class specified for parameter 'a'
  void fun(auto int a)*

Comment: Why not just pick up a book on C and read it?

Comment: @EdHeal To be fair, most books probably won't cover this rule.

Answer (score 3):

Because the standard says so. See *6.7.6.3p2*:

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is `register`.

Storage class specifiers usually don't make sense for function parameters.

Comment: Excellent, The quote is also specified [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration#Explanation).

Comment: Yes, I know that register can be used as a storage type . But, my question is why we can not use auto keyword in place of register keyword.

Comment: @YashPaliwal But what would it mean to have an `auto` parameter? Or a `static` one?

Comment: As we know 'auto' is a default storage type for all local variable (which are declared inside the block) and formal parameters of a function are considerd to be the local parameters of that particular function.  So their should be no issue of error while using auto keyword in formal parameter.

Comment: @YashPaliwal Yes, but the semantics of `auto` are already there without any storage class specifier. And, unlike local variables, there is no other option for parameters (`static`, `extern`, etc). As you know, `register` is really just `auto` with a hint (same lifetime, same scope, same linkage). So, in the context of parameters, they allowed `register` just to enable you to express that hint -- because anything other than the hint (e.g. lifetime, scope, linkage) can't be changed.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis thanks for explaining , this may be one of the reason for not using _auto_ in formal parameter.

Answer (score 1):

All that the `static` keyword does in that program is it tells the compiler (essentially) 'hey, I have a variable here that I don't want anyone else accessing, don't tell anyone else it exists'.

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter
>   declaration is register.

**strong text**